# How to open all the url in one page and keep the url the same in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I am using Wordpress. I have a page called `services` and I want any string or hierarchy url comes after `services` just opens the same page and also the url stays the same.

For example:

```
https://dev.new.oxbridgeessays.com/services/catergory/subcategory/page
```

goes to:

```
https://dev.new.oxbridgeessays.com/services/
```

But the url stays the same.

---

Here is my htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch ^services(/.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/services/ [L,R=301]
```

Is there any way that I can achieve this?

Comment: You will have to use WP's rewrite API instead of mod_rewrite rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @anubhava

A little study about [WP Rewrite API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule) find out the solution.

1) I have created a custom rewrite url and placed it into my functions.php

```
function services_rewrite_basic() {
  add_rewrite_rule('^services/.*', 'index.php?page_id=110&level=$matches[1]&level=$matches[1]&level=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'services_rewrite_basic');
```

2) And finally just saved permlink page without any changes and it bloody does the trick.